# How to show defined value of DependencyProperty in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I want to show defined value of **Dependency Property**. I should be able to select value of **User Property**.

Example, `FontWeight` show defined value, 'Normal', 'Medium', 'Heavy', etc...

`FontWeight`'s defined value (Image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are defined as `enum` and converted from string to `enum` type when you write e.g. `FontWeight="Normal"` in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a Enum List

```
public class WeightList
    {
        public enum FontWeightList
        {
            Normal,
            Medium,
            Heavy
        }
    }
```

Then the Dependency Property should be Defined as like

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightSelectorProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("FontWeightSelector", typeof(WeightList.FontWeightList), typeof(ControlClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(WeightList.FontWeightList.Normal));

public WeightList.FontWeightList FontWeightSelector
{
    get { return (WeightList.FontWeightList)GetValue(FontWeightSelectorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontWeightSelectorProperty, value); }
}
```

Here `new UIPropertyMetadata(WeightList.FontWeightList.Medium)` sets the default value of the Property has `Normal`. In the DropDown Control Normal is the SelectedItem.